# What does it mean to randomly choose an integer from a constant?

Tags: notation, random-variables

In this  [paper](http://web.mit.edu/eboyle/www/LR-MPC-STOC12.pdf) on pg. 1241 under section 2.3 "The Elect Protocol" 2nd paragraph the author says

> Each party samples a random value $x_i$ from [n/k].

What does that mean? If there are n parties and k is a security parameter, you get another constant when you divide them.  How can you randomly sample from a constant?

Comment: I didn't read the external link, but I assume that $[n/k]$ is the integer part of $[n/k]$ (ie. rounding down) and that if $[n/k]=m$, then $x_i$ is some natural number $1, 2, ..., m$ and the probability of selecting any particular integer is $1/m$.. perhaps?

Comment: @Tom - That makes sense to me within the context of the paper.  I can mark your answer is right if you make another post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $[n/k]$ is the integer part of $n/k$ (rounding down). If $[n/k]=m$ then $x_i$ is some natural number $1 \leq x_i \leq m$ and since the choice is (uniformly) randomly chosen, then for every $k \in \{1, 2, ..., m\}$, $P(x_i = k) = 1/m$.